# Using "object" of mainfile, in function saved in other file

Tags: python, pdf, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

In my work, I am receiving orders in PDF file, while I need to rewrite them into Excel table. Both Excel file and PDF file have every time exact structure, that does not change, so I have decided to automate this process and create python script that will do it for me.

At the moment, I am about to end, I just need to write into excel file last data, but I am having serious issues, so serious, that I might need to rewrite/redesign half of my code (that has about 500 lines atm).

The "problem" is, that I have my code split into 3 files:

- main (the one I am executing)
- functions (where all complicated logical functions are stored)
- config (where constants and configuration is stored)

The problem, however is, that I have **in main file** constructor of xlsxwritter, which creates Excel files and sheets.

Exactly this:

```
# Creation of new EXCEL file
xlsx_file = 'Red_vyplaty_' + termin_file + '.xlsx'
print 'Creating excel file "%s"' % xlsx_file
excel_file = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx_file)

# Adding sheet, called "Listky_obce_nad_300"
obce_nad_300_sheet = excel_file.add_worksheet('Listky_obce_nad_300')
print 'Adding data sheet "Listky_obce_nad_300" into "%s"' % (xlsx_file)
obce_nad_300_sheet.set_column(0, 0, 2)
obce_nad_300_sheet.set_column(1, 1, 2)
```

But, I need(or want is more accurate) to create a function, **in functions file** that will have one imput, and based on this one imput, it will get data from config-constants file, and write them into this sheet(obce_nad_300_sheet).

The problem is, if i create function like:

```
def create_footer(suma_cell, starting_row, flag):
    """
    Function to creade footer of listok
    flag = 0 / 1 / 2 (data sheet where to write header)
    """
    obce_nad_300_sheet.write(row, 4, 'Test')
```

it will (obviously) throw exception, that global variable obce_nad_300_sheet does not exist, bla bla bla..im sure you all know it :)

I know, that I have 2 options how to solve it:

1. Move whole creating and adding and writting into worksheet from main.py, into functions.py

   - that could do it, but, it would be too much work for me, and most of those new functions will be just calling one xlsxwritter function, so kinda waste of time
2. Create these new function in main.py file

   - while I am not sure if it would work, I am sure, that having some functions in function.py file, and others in main.py file, will be totally ugly and against my rules of clear code.

BUT I would like to have 3rd option, that I am not aware of yet and will be both, simple and "nice"??? :)

PS: *No, xlsxWritter is not able to open/read excel file, it can only create new one, so if i define it inside function, it will rewrite everything I have written into file before.*

Comment: It is kinda like, you have 2 files: main and stuff, you create connection "conn" in main file, and than you want to create functions that calls different combination of "conn.send(data)" in functions file. But it says, that global variable "conn" is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that your code is not very well organized. Without entering into too much trouble, I would use `obce_nad_300_sheet` as an object an move it around. Like this:

```
def create_footer(sheet, suma_cell, starting_row, flag):
    """
    Function to creade footer of listok
    flag = 0 / 1 / 2 (data sheet where to write header)
    """
    sheet.write(row, 4, 'Test')
```

I don't know how the library works however. Does it "commit" the changes with a call to `write` or need some sort of a `save` or `commit` method after that?

---

Without knowing too much about your situation nor the library, I would probably create an object inheriting from `xlsxwriter.Workbook`, store the sheets in an attribute of that object (probably a dict of `{"sheet_name": WorkSheet}`) and write the methods in the object. It could look like this:

```
class MyWorksheet(xlsxwriter.Workbook):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [...]
        super(MyWorksheet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sheets = {}
        [...]

    def add_worksheet(self, name):
        [...]
        self.sheets[name] = super(MyWorksheet, self).add_worksheet(name)
        [...]

    def create_footer(self, sheet_name, suma_cell, starting_row, flag):
        [...]
        self.sheets[sheet_name].write(row, 4, "Test")
        [...]
```

And then in what you call `main` file do:

```
my_sheet = MyWorksheet()
my_sheet.add_worksheet("Listky_obce_nad_300")

my_sheet.create_footer("Listky_obce_nad_300", suma, starting, flag)
```

Comment: Yes, it commit just simply by calling "write", no other approving needed to get it written into file.

However, I still feel like this answer is just little bit changed my "option number 1", I need completely rework whole xlsx file creating.